# Is MVC Controller overkill for one page

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've refactored my web application into one page (single page app). I'm just wanting some advice on whether serving up the one page `index.cshtml` with a controller is overkill (I'm not using any razor code that can't be substituted for normal html/js). Should I just change it to be a `index.html` page and just serve it as normal?

I'm sure it's only a minor thing, but want to know what the best practice is here.

Comment: Is this a static page or do you have some ajax calls in there?

Comment: There is some pretty intense javascript in the page. All asynchronous loading is done through requireJS and KendoUI.

Comment: The question is not whether MVC is overkill.. it's whether it's needed at all.  If you're not doing any server-side logic, then there is no reason to write a server-side application, regardless of the technology you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not an overkill.
Just split your code into 3 parts: logics, HTTP processing, view.
It will be MVC even if all 3 parts are in 1 file.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no need for MVC and all that BS.JS huge files when you're building a single page portfolio.
Just create a new HTML file.